# Why does Marionette.js need JSON2.js?

Tags: javascript, json, marionette

On the Marionette [downloads](http://marionettejs.com/#download) page, on the 'prerequisites' section, is stated: "Marionette relies on Underscore, Backbone, jQuery, and various other libraries as it's foundation."

Within the list of prerequisites, I see JSON2.js, does anybody know what it is used for and if it's really required for basic usage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON support came to browsers rather late. While current browsers all support `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`, in old browsers this behaviour had to be shimmed in, and JSON2 was a great library to do so.

You do not need JSON2 unless you intend to support ancient environments that should die a painful death as soon as possible.

Comment: To subtilize Amadan's answer a bit: this means native JSON support in Internet Explorer 8+, Firefox 3.1+, Safari 4+, Chrome 3+, and Opera 10.5+